# find duration of video using url in swift

Tags: swift

I have url of a video. 
I want to know the duration of it without playing it.

I tried this:

```
let data = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"
let a = NSURL(string: data)
let asset = AVAsset(URL: a!)

let duration = asset.duration
let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

print("the duration is",durationTime)
```

Comment: And? what happened? An error message an non-sensical result?

Comment: no error massage  it print "the duration is 0.0"

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this if the video is picked form `picker`

```
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: video)
        let durationInSeconds = asset.duration.seconds
        print(durationInSeconds)
```

Comment: didn't get it. please explain little bit more.

Comment: pass your URL in place of video.